# How to set the precision of a decimal context for a Class (Python using the decimal module)

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, precision

I am using the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and want to set the context of a Class to a specific precision.

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

ctx = decimal.getcontext()
ctx.prec = 6

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, id: str, int_val: int, float_val: float):
        self.id = id
        self.int_val = int_val
        self.float_val = Decimal(float_val)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
           return f"ID: {self.id}, Integer value: {self.int_val}, Float value: {self.float_val}\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyClass('001', 42, 304.00006)
    print(obj)
```

The above gives:

> ID: 001, Integer value: 42, Float value: 304.00006000000001904481905512511730194091796875

Whereas, I would expect to get

> ID: 001, Integer value: 42, Float value:
> 304.000  # i.e. precision of 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the [decimal module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) more carefully where it states that:

> prec is an integer in the range [1, MAX_PREC] that sets the precision for arithmetic operations in the context.

In other words,the `prec` attribute of the context controls the precision maintained
for **new values created as a result of arithmetic**. Literal values are maintained as described.

Hence, changing the constructor to initialise the `float_val` as a result of a simple arithmetic did the trick:

```
self.float_val = Decimal(float_val) * 1
```

which enforces the precision and returns the desired result:

> ID: 001, Integer value: 42, Float value: 304.000

Comment: `+Decimal(float_val)` also works, and is the standard-ish way of rounding a value to the current context.